# 14.04 LTS - Wifi Drops in 1500 - 1800 seconds - DHCP lease get renewed

Tags: wireless, dhcp, iwlwifi

Wifi drops regularly. And tried

1. Adding in file /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf

   options iwlwifi 11n_disable=0  -> (Did not work)
2. Uncommented:  in file /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

   send dhcp-lease-time 3600;  -> (Still nothing worked)

system log most of the time reports :

"dhclient: bound to 192.168.0.14 -- renewal in 1799 seconds."

(Something around 1500 - 1800 seconds for renewal)

How can I change this since wifi always drops in 30mins ??

Comment: 11n_disable=0 is the default. You didn't change anything. I'd try =8 or =1. What is your wireless device? lspci -nn | grep 0280 What is the lease time as set in the router? Thanks.

Comment: My wireless device is:02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)

The lease time in router is 14400 S (which I changed from 3600S)

I tried 11n_disable=1 didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the following, in a terminal:

```
echo "options iwlmvm power_scheme=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlmvm.conf
echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=Y swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Reboot and let us hear your report.

You might also try:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases
sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-xxxxx-wlan0.lease
```

Where xxxxx is a long string of numbers you can find with:

```
ls /var/lib/NetworkManager
```

Then restart NM:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And check the lease time:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i dhc
```

Comment: tried both the commands:  
files iwlmvn.conf & iwlwifi.conf has those commands appended.  
After rebooting still :  
System Log  
dhclient: bound to 192.168.0.14 -- renewal in 1701 seconds

Comment: But then does it drop as before? Did you restart after the change to dhclient.conf?

Comment: I restarted after the earlier given change
bt didn't do any changes to the dhclient.conf ??   
what is the change I shld do there ?  
Also the drops r mainly noticeable when taking Skype calls since it reconnects all the time. But is there way to see the drops other than the systemlogs.

Comment: In your question, you said, "Uncommented: in file /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf: send dhcp-lease-time 3600;" Did you reboot after that? I'd probably actually change that to _send dhcp-lease-time 36000;_ and then reboot. Check: cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i dhc

Comment: Yes. I did reboot earlier with that change.
Now I have made lease-time=36000 and rebooted. 


Jan  8 21:31:18 nitish-Inspiron-5547 dhclient: bound to 192.168.0.14 -- renewal in 1465 seconds.
Jan  8 21:55:44 nitish-Inspiron-5547 dhclient: bound to 192.168.0.14 -- renewal in 1593 seconds.
Jan  8 22:22:17 nitish-Inspiron-5547 dhclient: bound to 192.168.0.14 -- renewal in 1520 seconds.
Jan  8 22:47:37 nitish-Inspiron-5547 dhclient: bound to 192.168.0.14 -- renewal in 1468 seconds.
Jan  8 22:48:44 nitish-Inspiron-5547 dhclient: bound to 192.168.0.14 -- renewal in 1654 seconds.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: I you have mensioned I deleted the files and restarted the NM but still the renewal times are similar  


Jan 10 01:41:53 nitish-Inspiron-5547 dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.14 from 192.168.0.1
Jan 10 01:41:53 nitish-Inspiron-5547 dhclient: bound to 192.168.0.14 -- renewal in 1765 seconds.

Comment: I regret that I have no other ideas or suggestions. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Hope this would be fixed some new kernel update.